# .find adds multiple comments

Tags: vba, while-loop, ms-word, find

The intention is to find all ocurrances of myWord in a word document and add the same comment to them. I get two unwanted effects: 1) the code adds more than 1 comment on each instance of the word (it seems to add the same number of commens as the number of instances of that word), and 2) the code skips words with capital letters.

```
Sub CheckWrd()
For Each myWord in wordArray            'wrdArray is a list of words loaded elsewhere
  With Selection.Find
   .Text = "[^13^11 ]" & wrd & "[^13^11 ,-.]"
   .Forward = True
   .Wrap = wdFindContinue
   .MatchCase = False
   .MatchWholeWord = True
  End With
  Do While Selection.Find.Execute = True
    ActiveDocument.Comments.Add Selection.range, myComment
  Loop
Next myWord
```

Additionally, if I change the Do While construct to and If then, it adds commets only to the first instance of myWord.

Comment: Try starting at the top of the document and changing the value of `.Wrap` to `wdFindStop`

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping the `execute` loop inside the `with` statement. This code works for me (using a test file with multiple variations on capitalization):

```
Sub find_test()
    i = 1
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .Text = "test"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        While .Execute() = True
            .Parent.Select
            ActiveDocument.Comments.Add Selection.Range, "test" & i
            i = i + 1
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Kevin, thanks for the answer. That code still produces the same unwanted effect for me. I should point out that unlike your code, that section of my program is whithin a For Each loop as shown above. That is the only difference I can see from you suggested and what I changed my code to.

Comment: Also, using vbFindStop works fine when there is 1 of each word but does not catch a any following repetitions of that word i.e. if looking for "test1" in "This is a test1, test1, test1" it will only highlight the first test1.

Comment: Interesting - perhaps I don't understand the problem.  For me, in Word 2010, my code adds a single comment to each instance of "test" in my test document, regardless of the capitalisation of the instance.  Does `wordArray` have multiple instances of each word you're trying to comment?

Comment: Hmm, strange.  In testing a bit further, I've found that using the `Selection.Find` object doesn't get me what I'd expect, so I used the `ActiveDocument.Content.Find`, but had to run the `.Parent.Select` for each object found.  Good luck, and sorry I couldn't help!

Answer (score 0):

**The Answer:**

In the While add an .Execute to move things along. I don't really know how or why this works, but it does (it's voodoo magic).

(...)

`Do While Selection.Find.Execute = True
    ActiveDocument.Comments.Add Selection.range, myComment
    .Execute
Loop`